# Making Ansible use non-empty shell environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

When executing ad-hoc commands or play-books, I am running into a situation where the ENV Vars from the `/home/user-that-sudoed/.bashrc` needs to be read for the ad-hoc command or playbook to work on the destination inventory host. Inside that `.bashrc` file we have setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (necessary for some of the Python functions we are using).

Is there a parameter in `/home/local-user/.ansible.cfg` that can effectively turn "`/bin/sh -c`" into "`/bin/sh`" with no "`-c`"? the "`-c`" (command run is below).

```
ssh -q -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/.ansible/sockets/5c2164546a zlpv1229 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u atg /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-cyhlvtntyqmbkkmcpkhhkspusdirgwlk; /sites/utils/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
```

The connection is made as "`user@controller` to `user@inventory_host`, then `user@inventory_host` is becoming '`user-that-sudoed`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible permits to set environment variables using the `environment` keyword for a single task

**example**

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - shell: /opt/local/my-binary
      environment:
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/my/dir/
```

or this is also possible to set `environment` for a playbook

```
- hosts: all

  environment:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/my/dir/

  tasks:
    …
```

so that would be better to than try to do the way you propose.

Hope it helps

Official documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: Whats the equivalent for doing this with adhoc command line uses of ansible?

Comment: This is not possible, I did not notice you wanted to do ad-hoc command.

Comment: Thanks, I am a user who does RTFM, I was able to get everything to work. I just recompiled Python with "rpath" and all is well.